# Jfrog propagate GPG Signing keys for Distribution

Tags: jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, gpg-signature

I have to sign the release bundles I created under distribution. I generated gpg as in the jfrog document [1] and uploaded it both with the interface and with the rest API [2] but when I want to sign my release bundle, I can't see the signing key I created.

1. https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-distribution-documentation/gpg-signing
2. https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/upload-and-propagate-gpg-signing-keys-for-distribution

Comment: what responses do you get when you: 1. set the GPG key, 2. propagate it

Answer (score 0):

Here are two CURL examples you should use
{{jfrog_platform_url}} - your jfrog url
{{token}} - and admin token for your environment

#### Set the GPG key

```
curl -X POST
'https://{{jfrog_platform_url}}/distribution/api/v1/keys/pgp' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{token}}' \
--data '{
    "set_as_default": true,
    "key": {
        "alias": "TheKEY",
        "public_key": "{{public_GPG_key}}",
        "private_key": "{{private_GPG_key}}"
    }
}'
```

#### Propagate it

```
curl -X POST 'https://{{jfrog_platform_url}}/distribution/api/v1/keys/pgp/propagate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{token}}'
```